# How to connect to guest vm(KVM) on remote host PC

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization, virtualization

I have dedicated server with ip.
 I installed KVM, launched virtual machine(Centos), vm has internet connection(NAT), I installed and launched openssh server (22 port).
How can I connect to that VM via ssh?
Yes, i can connect to host pc via ssh, then from host pc connect to VM via ssh. But I want to connect to VM directly, without typing host PC password.
I think, i need forward ports? how to do that in right way?
P.S. host pc uses ppp0

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need to set up a bridge on your host and assign IP(s) to your VM(s) in order to connect directly via ssh. Here is an example setup on this link (under title "Public Bridge"): http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have only 1 static ip for server. I can't understand how to differ  22 port of host pc and 22 port on VM at the same public IP. I want to have access <myPublicIp>:22 to my host server and allow access to VMs on other ports.
for e.q.: 
<local VM1 address on host>:22 will be allowed on  <myPublicIp>:2222
<local VM2 address on host>:22 will be allowed on  <myPublicIp>:3333
etc.

Comment: So you cannot get / assign IPs for your VMs, is that right?

Comment: yes, i have only 1 ip for my host pc;
I solved that problem by transmitting input packets from my host's ports to internal VM's ports

Comment: @IgorKasuan please post an answer with what you did to solve this (I'm guessing NAT rules with iptables?)

Answer (score 0):

## kvm -net user,hostfwd=::1234-:22

There are many good answers to this, but I think the simplest is to use `qemu-system`'s builtin host forwarding ability.

```
 kvm -hda devonshire.img -net nic -net user,hostfwd=::1234-:22
```

Any connections to the host machine on port 1234 will be sent to the guest machine on port 22 (ssh).

#### Man qemu-system

That's all you need, but if you're curious, here's the what the manual page for `qemu-system` has to say about the `hostfwd` option:

> **-net** **user**[,option][,option][,...]
>
> Use the user mode network stack which requires no administrator privilege to run. Valid options are:
>
> > **hostfwd=**[**tcp**|**udp**] **:** [*hostaddr*] **:** *hostport* **-** [*guestaddr*] **:** *guestport*
> >
> > Redirect incoming TCP or UDP connections to the host port
> >                    *hostport* to the guest IP address *guestaddr* on guest port
> >                    *guestport*. If *guestaddr* is not specified, its value is x.x.x.15
> >                    (default first address given by the built-in DHCP server). By
> >                    specifying *hostaddr*, the rule can be bound to a specific host
> >                     interface. If no connection type is set, TCP is used. This
> >                    option can be given multiple times.
> >
> > For example, to redirect host X11 connection from screen 1 to
> >                    guest screen 0, use the following:
> >
> > ```
> > # on the host
> > qemu-system-i386 -net user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:6001-:6000 [...]
> > # this host xterm should open in the guest X11 server
> > xterm -display :1
> > ```
> >
> > To redirect telnet connections from host port 5555 to telnet
> >         port on the guest, use the following:
> >
> > ```
> > # on the host
> > qemu-system-i386 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:23 [...]
> > telnet localhost 5555
> > ```
> >
> > Then when you use on the host `telnet localhost 5555`, you
> >                    connect to the guest telnet server.